# php artisan is not working and showing Fatal error Uncaught Error: Class "Illuminate\Foundation\Application" bootsrap\app.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I tried following:

```
 composer install
    composer update
    composer update --no-scripts
    composer dump-autoload
```

I have also deleted the vendor folder and composer.log but still, the same error please someone help.

it shows the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Illuminate\Foundation\Application" not found in C:\Users\M Abbas\Documents\Edoc-Editor.com\bootstrap\app.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\M Abbas\Documents\Edoc-Editor.com\artisan(20): require_once()
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\Users\M Abbas\Documents\Edoc-Editor.com\bootstrap\app.php on line 14
```

Comment: Just remove the files from bootstrap\cache
and also from storage\logs\laravel.log
just run the mentioned command:
composer install
composer update

Comment: Tried but same error brother

Comment: didn't anyone get this error

Comment: how did your create the laravel project? What command did you use?

Comment: composer create-project laravel/laravel MyProjectName

Comment: what is the laravel version and php version that you used?

Comment: php version 8.1 and laravel is 9

Comment: Can you please copy'n'paste the error message _as_ _text_ into your question? It allows (hint!) searching for it.

Comment: can someone solve this issue